# Do <span> tags hurt in regards to SEO?

Tags: seo

For example would the following code penalize you in regards to SEO?

`<h2>Singles events across the UK! <span>Including Bristol, Manchester, London, Birmingham &amp; Newcastle.</span></h2>`

Would the content inside the `<span>` tags be regarded as less important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag on its own shouldn't, but be wary if you're setting the span to `display: none` in a deliberate attempt to hack SEO, you may get penalised.

Answer (score 0):

You can never be sure about SEO but the answer is no, it doesn't hurt the search engine rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Span is not required in the header tag, unless for a purpose (when an author wishes to assign style information to a set of elements). The documents are being read by a machine which are fed specific instructions and structure to process the meaning of that content. It depends.

Comment: The `<span>` tag is required for a colour change for part of the text? So what depends?